# show data from pivot table in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

How can I display data from the pivot table?

I want to display the `user` who the `project` belongs to alongside the `user` who logged in and the `project` being worked on, as well as their respective roles.

Do I use `->groupBy()`?

**View: index.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-consended">
  <tr>
     <th> <h4>No</h4> </th>
     <th> <h4>Name</h4> </th>
     <th> <h4>Role</h4> </th>
     <th> <h4>Project</h4> </th>
  </tr>
     @foreach($users as $item => $user)
  <tr>
      <td>{{$item+1}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->projects->project_name}}</td>
  </tr>
     @endforeach()
</table>
```

**my controller.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $projects = User::pluck('name')->where('project_id', 3);
    $projects = Project::all();   
    return view ('teams.index', compact ('user_projects', 'users', 'projects'));
}
```

**Models User.php**

```
<?php

class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::Class, 'user_projects');
    }
}
```

**Models Project.php**

```
<?php

class Project extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'projects';
    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id',
        'project_name',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'project_category',
    ];

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_projects');
    }
}
```

and I have table pivot `user_projects` have `user_id` and `project_id`

[image: form]

[image: mockup]

Comment: Your controller has a missing `$user_projects` variable, which is passed through using `compact()`.

Comment: You are also replacing `$projects` in this controller.

Comment: `user_projects` is not using

Comment: I want to display user name which one project with user login. I have pivot table user_project, it has user_id and project_id. Should I using groupBy?

Answer (score 0):

You are misleading basic concepts. You have defined a **many to many relation** between `users` and `projects` through a pivot table, which is fine (models are fine). 
But your **controller** and **view** code are wrong. An approach to...

- ...show **all of the users that have a project in common with the logged in user**...
- ...along with the **project name in which they are working together** (through *pivot table*)...
- ...and assuming that you have correctly implemented **basic Auth** in Laravel could be:

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();    // logged in user
    $coworkers = [];         // coworkers array
    $projects = [];          // projects array

    foreach ($user->projects as $project) {
        foreach($project->users as $coworker) {
            $coworkers[] = $coworker;
            $projects[] = $project;
        }
    }
    return view ('teams.index', ['coworkers' => $coworkers, 'projects' => $projects]);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-consended">
  <tr>
     <th> <h4>No</h4> </th>
     <th> <h4>Name</h4> </th>
     <th> <h4>Role</h4> </th>
     <th> <h4>Project</h4> </th>
  </tr>

  @foreach($coworkers as $coworker)
      <tr>
          <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
          <td>{{$coworker->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$coworker->role->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$projects[$loop->index]->name}}</td>
       </tr>
  @endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: if not using compact, then the `users` in the view cannot be accessed

Comment: but I want other user can't see project other people, except for one project, then he can see user and their project

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Could you please clear things up here and in the main question so I can help you better? Please, pay attention to English

Comment: display user name, who has same project with user logged in. and show project name. i will show the form in my question.

Comment: Ok, see the new answer again

Comment: something error `Undefined variable: project (View: D:\PPI\astrowatch\resources\views\teams\index.blade.php)`

Comment: It was `$projects` indeed in view. Corrected :)

Comment: it works, but its not display his project. like mockup

Comment: Perhaps you should have uploaded the mockup at first :( See new code